# How to convert Unix timestamp into EST time in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert Unix timestamp into EST time in Wordpress. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?
Thanks.

Here is a code to convert ISO timestamp to EST time. I want similar to convert Unix to EST.

```
function ptr_filter( $rdamtmp )
{
if( preg_match_all( "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}/", $rdamtmp, $matches) )
{
    foreach( $matches[0] as $m )
    {
        $time = strtotime( $m );

        $timezone  = -4; //(GMT -4:00) EST (U.S. & Canada)

        $text = gmdate( "l g:i a", $time + 3600 * ( $timezone + date("I") ) );

        $rdamtmp = str_replace( $m, $text, $rdamtmp );
    }
}

return $rdamtmp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($unixtimestamp);
$datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $datetime->format('m/d/Y H:i:s T');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Flint. I have a function to convert ISO timestamp to EST date.

function ptr_filter( $rdamtmp )
{
 if( preg_match_all( "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}/", $rdamtmp, $matches) )
 {
  foreach( $matches[0] as $m )
  {
   $time = strtotime( $m );

   $timezone  = -4; //(GMT -4:00) EST (U.S. & Canada)

   $text = gmdate( "l g:i a", $time + 3600 * ( $timezone + date("I") ) );

   $rdamtmp = str_replace( $m, $text, $rdamtmp );
  }
 }

 return $rdamtmp;

}

Now, I want the similar function to convert Unix timestamp to EST time.

Comment: Wow, that function is waaaay above my pay grade.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Flint.